# fancybox inline with parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, inline

I have the following code

```
<a href="#inline" class="fancy" id="item1">hello item1</a>
<a href="#inline" class="fancy" id="item2">hello item2</a>

<div id='inline'><input name="" type="text" value="hello 1" /></div>

$(".fancy").fancybox();
```

I want to change the value of text-field dynamically with the parameter.
is there any techniques or ways to pass id as a parameter.

**p.s** i am not interested in ajax implementation.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, i found the solution

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:display('id=1');">hello item1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:display('id=2');">hello item2</a>

function display (id) {
  $.fancybox('<div id='inline'><input type="text" value="hello item '+id+'" /></div>');
}
```

thanks all the help.

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
$('.fancy').click(function(){
    $('#inline > input').val($(this).attr('id'));
})
```

is that what you mean?

Comment: not sure I understand the question then? what is it you're trying to achieve? is it you're trying to change the text of the a href?

Comment: nop, i want to call the same div "inline" but change values inside the text-box from the parameter it gets.

Comment: Sorry still don't really get what you're trying to achieve. That code above will change the content of the textbox to the id of the hyperlink you click. Which in turn will load up a fancy box of what you've clicked as well...

Comment: @SimonLongson: what he wants is to open the `<div id="inline">` in fancybox with a button where the `value` field will be changed depending on what link fired fancybox (the two links above have the same `class="fancy"` which is used to fire fancybox but they have different `ID` which I guess will be used as reference to pass the parameter to the `value` field) ... so that could be achieved within a callback function inside the fancybox script.

Comment: @JFK that exactly what i want.